# C, custom reading from file into struct

Tags: c, scanf, structure, fgets

Can you guys please check this and tell me what am I doing wrong?

I am trying to read from a txt into a struct

The file looks like this: (name on a line, followed by 4 attributes on the next line)

```
NAME SURNAME OTHER
a1 a2 a4 a3
OTHER ANOTHER
s2 s3 s4 s5
```

I have to read the file into a struct, then search for a name and print the number of comparisons it took till you found it (the names in the file are alphabetically sorted - I guess binary search is optimal).

Here is what I wrote for now:
*note: I know for certain that the file will have 10000 lines and the full name has at most 40 chars

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char name[40];
    char arg1[10];
    char arg2[10];
    char arg3[10];
    char arg4[10];
}STUD;

STUD studies[5000];
STUD *ptr = studies;

void readlines(FILE *f)
{
    char line[40];
    char secondline[40];
    int i=0;

    while(fgets(line, 40, f) != NULL) //read first line -> here has to be student's name
    {
        sscanf(line, "%[^\n]%*c\n", studies[i].name); //store first line ->student's name
        fgets(secondline, 40, f); //read second line -> here has to be additional information 
        sscanf(secondline, "%s %s %s %s", studies[i].arg1, studies[i].arg2, studies[i].arg3, studies[i].arg4);

        i++;
    }
}


void binary_search_string(STUD *arr, char x[])
{
    //printf("sizeof: %ld\n", sizeof(arr));
    int l=0;
    int r = 4999;
    int mid;
    int compare=0;

    while(l <= r)
    {
        mid = (l + r)/2;
        printf("%s\n", studies[mid].name);
        if(strcmp(studies[mid].name, x) == 0)
        {
            compare++;
            printf("%d comparisons to find %s\n", compare, x);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(strcmp(studies[mid].name, x) < 0)
            {
                compare++;
                l = mid + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                compare++;
                r = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        //printf("compare: %d\n", compare);
    }
    
}

void print(STUD *array)
{
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(array); i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", studies[i].name, studies[i].arg1, studies[i].arg2, studies[i].arg3, studies[i].arg4);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./exe file_to_open\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char x[]="SURNAME NAME";

    readlines(fp);
    print(studies);
    binary_search_string(studies, x);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Another thing I am not sure about is how would the function "readlines" look like when using the pointer to the array of struct (ptr). (Can you guys give me an example here?)

I am sorry in advance if this is a stupid question.
Thank you!

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" What makes you think that something is wrong?

Comment: the function binary_search_string does not print the correct value of comparisons. I tested it on a file with 5 entries (5 complete students) and it printed 13 comparisons- how?!

Comment: What output did that get? What input did you use? What output do you epxect? How is the output you get wrong, apart from not being the one you expect.  please provde more details, as described for [ask] and ideally as a [mre].